# Create BitmapImage and apply to it a specific Color

Tags: c#, wpf

I got stuck how to create  `BitmapImage`   based on some **color value**?

For example I have string "*Black*" so I need black **BitmapImage**.

How it could be done?

Thank you!

-- UPDATES (I put this code for **@StephenChung**)

The idea is to do Grid with any opacity and don't apply opacity to its children.
So I create an image by ANY color I need and apply opacity for it.

```
BitmapSource bs = CreateBitmapSource(GetBackgroundColorValue());
// and here I use method of @StaWho CreateBitmapSource()
ImageBrush ib2 = new ImageBrush(bs);
ib2.Opacity = Opacity;
ib2.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
RootGrid.Background = ib2;
```

Comment: Create a blank BitmapImage and fill it with black?

Comment: @StephenChung Yes yes something like this. How to do it?

Comment: Does it have to be `BitmapImage` or can it be `BitmapSource`?

Comment: @StaWho In fact I need BitmapImage because I have to create  ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush(bitmapImage);

Comment: You can create `ImageBrush` from `BitmapSource`. Look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx)

Comment: @StaWho I didn't know it... Thanks man!

Comment: May I ask why you need a completely black ImageBrush?  Why not use a SolidColorBrush?

Comment: @StephenChung Sure. In fact I asked for an ANY color to apply.But I didn't new that is possible to use BitmapSource to make ImageBrush. I will put the code under my question so u can understand my approach better.

Comment: Hhhhmmmm.... what can an ImageBrush filled with a single color do where a SolidColorBrush can't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create `ImageBrush` from `BitmapSource`:

```
    private BitmapSource CreateBitmapSource(System.Windows.Media.Color color)
    {
        int width = 128;
        int height = width;
        int stride = width / 8;
        byte[] pixels = new byte[height * stride];

        List<System.Windows.Media.Color> colors = new List<System.Windows.Media.Color>();
        colors.Add(color);
        BitmapPalette myPalette = new BitmapPalette(colors);

        BitmapSource image = BitmapSource.Create(
            width,
            height,
            96,
            96,
            PixelFormats.Indexed1,
            myPalette,
            pixels,
            stride);

        return image;
    }
```

Comment: I got an error on larger width/height. I fixed it by setting the stride to `int stride = width;` maybe there is just one byte per pixel if the palette is set.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap flag = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(10, 10);
for( int x = 0; x <  flag.Height; ++x )
    for( int y = 0; y < flag.Width; ++y )
        flag.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
for( int x = 0; x < flag.Height; ++x )
    flag.SetPixel(x, x, Color.Black);
```

and the conversion:

```
private BitmapImage Bitmap2BitmapImage(Bitmap bitmap) 
{ 
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) 
    { 
        bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png); 
        ms.Position = 0; 
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(); 
        bi.BeginInit(); 
        bi.StreamSource = ms; 
        bi.EndInit(); 

        return bi; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants to first find a color given a string. And SetPixel is terribly slow. It should be avoided if possible.